# Value insertions from Matrix to array cells issue

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of values as given below.

```
candidate_edges =
   10.0000   10.0000    6.0000
  155.5000  105.5000   75.5000
   25.5000  105.5000   75.5000
  295.5000  415.5000  155.5000
  185.5000  415.5000  155.5000
  185.5000  485.5000  155.5000
  195.5000  305.5000   74.5000
  115.5000  305.5000   74.5000
  115.5000  395.5000   74.5000
  195.5000  395.5000   74.5000
   25.5000  185.5000   75.5000
  155.5000  185.5000   75.5000
  295.5000  415.5000    5.5000
  295.5000  415.5000  155.5000
  185.5000  415.5000  155.5000
  195.5000  305.5000    5.5000
  195.5000  305.5000   74.5000
  195.5000  395.5000   74.5000
  295.5000  415.5000    5.5000
  195.5000  395.5000    5.5000
  295.5000  485.5000    5.5000
  300.0000  600.0000         0
  295.5000  415.5000  155.5000
  185.5000  415.5000  155.5000
```

I want to generate an array with length 1: length(candidate_edges) and in each cell, I want to store each row of the above matrix. Below is my code

```
cnode = zeros(1, n);
cnode = cell(1, n);
for k = 1:length(cnode)
    for j = 1:length(candidate_edges)
        cnode{k} = candidate_edges(j,:);
    end
end
```

In the output, I get only same value in each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need two loops. e.g. this should do

```
cnode = cell(1, size(candidate_edges, 1))
for k = 1:numel(cnode)
    cnode{k} = candidate_edges(k,:);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the inbuilt MATLAB function `mat2cell` for the same like this:

```
cnode = mat2cell(candidate_edges, ones(1, size(candidate_edges, 1)));
```